# "Stack Exchange chat" logo links to main Stack Exchange site

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat, user-interface, stackexchange.com

In chat, some pages, like https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/1, have a "Stack Exchange chat" logo at the top:

[image: Stack Exchange chat]

One expects that clicking on the "Stack Exchange chat" logo would take you to [the Stack Exchange chat home page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/). But in fact, it links to the main Stack Exchange site, https://stackexchange.com/ (including if you click on the word "chat").

Comment: The logos in each chat have the same affect. It is not specific to this one.